# How to calculate Sum of 2 Count(*) in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that I count rows of them.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM docgrados_directores 
WHERE docgrados_directoresleido = '0' AND docgrados_directoresusu = '11' 

result 1

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM docgrados_lectores 
WHERE docgrados_lectoresleido = '0' AND docgrados_lectoresusu = '11'

result 1
```

I need total count (result would be 2). How can I sum the result with a single statement? What is the correct syntax??

Comment: We need to know some relevant schema. How are these tables related?

Comment: I need the sum of the number of rows in each select, 2 should be the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another `SELECT` to add the scalar values returned by your queries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM docgrados_directores 
        WHERE docgrados_directoresleido = '0' AND docgrados_directoresusu = '11' ) 
       +    
      (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM docgrados_lectores 
       WHERE docgrados_lectoresleido = '0' AND docgrados_lectoresusu = '11')
```

The above statement should return `2` as result if the result of both subqueries is a `1`.

Comment: That's what I needed :)